# How to verify sprng kafka producer has successfully sent message or not?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-kafka

I am trying to test spring kafka(2.2.5.RELEASE) where when producer send message with kafkatemplate, i like to know if that message was sent successfully or not. Based on that I would like to update the db record for that message id. What is the best practice to handle this scenario?

Here is the sample code which checks success or failure

```
ListenableFuture<SendResult<String, String>> future = kafkaTemplate.send("test_topic", key, userMsg);
    SendResult<String, String> result = null;
    try {
        result = future.get(10000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        LOGGER.info("Send Result : {}", result);
        LOGGER.info("Saving entry in db");
        messageRepo.save(result.getProducerRecord().key().toString(),result.getProducerRecord().value().toString());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOGGER.error("Error publishing message ", e);
        messageRepo.save(result.getProducerRecord().key().toString(),result.getProducerRecord().value().toString());
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `send()` operations return a `ListenableFuture<>` which is completed asynchronously.

If you want to block the calling thread to get the result, use

```
future.get(timeout, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

Comment: And I want to note, that 'ack' property should be set in '1' or 'all' value. If 'ack' is 0, there are no guarantees that the message is delivered. Correct me Gary if I'm wrong

Comment: Thank you Gary. Appreciate quick feedback.

Comment: @MaximPopov I think you mean `acks` - yes, but it defaults to 1, you have to explicitly set it to 0 if you want to disable it. `all` is the safest (but more expensive).

Comment: @GaryRussell - how do I get hold off message when listenableFuture calls onFailure() method? I like to know which message failed so that I can update proper record in db based on message id.

Comment: You should still have a reference to the record. Edit your question to show your sending code.

Comment: I have added code sample and looks like i do have information about actual message which was failed to be sent.

Comment: I tried to follow a similar approach mentioned in the code (original post) to check whether the record was sent successfully or not. Even if the topic did not exist, ```kafkaTemplate.send()``` did not fail. How can I validate whether it was delivered to the correct topic or not?

Comment: Don't ask new questions in comments; you must `get()` the result of the future (returned by the `send()`) to determine success or failure. By default, it will take 60 seconds for the get to fail when a topic is no present.

Comment: I will add a new question with the proper code to explain my issue.

Comment: Right now, I put the timeout of 10 seconds. Let me try by increasing that timeout to 60 seconds.

Comment: You can also reduce the Producer `max.block.ms` config from its default 60000.