# Validate Kafka producer message delivery

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-kafka

This question is on top of the discussion over here: [How to verify sprng kafka producer has successfully sent message or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60725906/how-to-verify-sprng-kafka-producer-has-successfully-sent-message-or-not). Below is my code to check whether kafka producer was able to send the record to the expected topic or not. To check whether the Exception is thrown or not, I put the topic name which does not exist at all.

```
@RestController
public class TestController {

    @Autowired
    MailProcessor processor;
    
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TestController.class);
    
    @GetMapping(path = "/mailman/{command}")
    public void testApp(@PathVariable("command") String action) {
        
        try {
            
            Envelope message = new Envelope();
            message.setAction(action);
            message.setValue("this is the sample message for testing purpose only");
            
            processor.sendMessage("notAvailableTopic", message);
            
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Exception in the test controller", e);
            
        }
    }
    
}
```

Here is the method implementation

```
public void sendMessage(String topic, Envelope message) {
        
        try {
            
            ListenableFuture<SendResult<String, Envelope>> future = kafkaTemplate.send(topic, message);
            SendResult<String, Envelope> result = future.get(65000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
            
            logger.info("Successful delivery of {}", result.getProducerRecord());
            
        }catch(Exception ex) {
            logger.error("Exception while sending to {} topic", topic, ex);
        }
        
    }
```

The kafkaTemplate is instantiated as below:

```
@Bean
    public List<String> consumerBootstrapServers(@Value("${kafka.bootstrap-servers}") String bootstrapServers) {
        return Arrays.asList(bootstrapServers.split(","));
    }

@Bean
    public ProducerFactory<String, Envelope> producerFactory(List<String> consumerBootstrapServers) {
        Map<String, Object> config = new HashMap<>();

        config.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, consumerBootstrapServers);
        config.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
        config.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonSerializer.class);

        return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(config);
    }


    @Bean
    public KafkaTemplate<String, Envelope> kafkaTemplate(ProducerFactory<String, Envelope> producerFactory) {
        return new KafkaTemplate<>(producerFactory);
    }
```

As mentioned in the previous post; `get()` will take 60 seconds to fail, I blocked the calling thread for 65 seconds. I could see below the logger statements.

```
2020-08-12 16:58:35.273  INFO 11471 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : Kafka version: 2.5.0
2020-08-12 16:58:35.273  INFO 11471 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : Kafka commitId: 66563e712b0b9f84
2020-08-12 16:58:35.273  INFO 11471 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : Kafka startTimeMs: 1597269515273
2020-08-12 16:58:35.466  WARN 11471 --- [ad | producer-4] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Producer clientId=producer-4] Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 2 : {notAvailableTopic=LEADER_NOT_AVAILABLE}
2020-08-12 16:58:35.467  INFO 11471 --- [ad | producer-4] org.apache.kafka.clients.Metadata        : [Producer clientId=producer-4] Cluster ID: KQOZN8MkRVqke4J4H8PDpA
2020-08-12 16:58:35.879  INFO 11471 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] c.w.gioda.po.worker.KafkaProducer        : Successful delivery of ProducerRecord(topic=notAvailableTopic, partition=null, headers=RecordHeaders(headers = [RecordHeader(key = __TypeId__, value = [99, 111, 109, 46, 119, 97, 108, 109, 97, 114, 116, 108, 97, 98, 115, 46, 103, 105, 111, 100, 97, 46, 112, 111, 46, 109, 111, 100, 101, 108, 46, 69, 110, 118, 101, 108, 111, 112, 101])], isReadOnly = true), key=null, value=Envelope [action=updateService, value=this is the sample message for testing purpose only], timestamp=null)
2020-08-12 17:00:17.984  INFO 11471 --- [uterTopic-0-C-1] o.a.kafka.clients.FetchSessionHandler    : [Consumer clientId=consumer-postOfficeGrp-7, groupId=postOfficeGrp] Node 244026236 was unable to process the fetch request with (sessionId=1472063313, epoch=179): FETCH_SESSION_ID_NOT_FOUND.
2020-08-12 17:00:18.655  INFO 11471 --- [uterTopic-0-C-1] o.a.kafka.clients.FetchSessionHandler    : [Consumer clientId=consumer-postOfficeGrp-7, groupId=postOfficeGrp] Node 1712770852 was unable to process the fetch request with (sessionId=1493387199, epoch=179): FETCH_SESSION_ID_NOT_FOUND.
2020-08-12 17:00:20.485  INFO 11471 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.kafka.clients.FetchSessionHandler    : [Consumer clientId=consumer-postOfficeGrp-8, groupId=postOfficeGrp] Node 457669866 was unable to process the fetch request with (sessionId=1173363358, epoch=179): FETCH_SESSION_ID_NOT_FOUND.
```

It did not print the log statement from the `catch()` block. How can I validate whether the message was successfully delivered to the Kafka topic or not? Am I missing something?

Comment: Writing to a non existent topic might actually work, depending on your Kafka configuration. I think the error you see is printed from an asynchronous thread, that's why you don't catch an exception.

Answer (score 1):

Please provide your complete test case.

I get the error as expected...

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class So63385353Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So63385353Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public ApplicationRunner runner(KafkaTemplate<String, String> template) {
        return args -> {
            try {
                template.send("missing", "foo").get(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        };
    }

}
```

```
spring.kafka.producer.properties.max.block.ms=5000
```

```
2020-08-13 09:49:08.653 ERROR 14921 --- [           main] o.s.k.support.LoggingProducerListener    : Exception thrown when sending a message with key='null' and payload='foo' to topic missing:

org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Topic missing not present in metadata after 5000 ms.

org.springframework.kafka.KafkaException: Send failed; nested exception is org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Topic missing not present in metadata after 5000 ms.
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate.doSend(KafkaTemplate.java:573)
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate.send(KafkaTemplate.java:363)
    at com.example.demo.So63385353Application.lambda$0(So63385353Application.java:22)
```

Comment: Can you please let me know what I might be missing? I can provide the code sample based on that. Because ```sendMessage()``` method mentioned above gets called whenever I want to send the message.

Comment: I have no idea without seeing the code; as I said it works as expected for me.

Comment: I added the code snippet that I am using to test the functionality. WIll that help?

Comment: It makes no sense to me; you must either get an exception because the producer completes the future with a `TimeoutException` or you must get a `TimeoutException` when the `get()` times oue.

Comment: Yeah, even I am confused about why I am not getting an Exception. Comparing your code, I should have got an Exception. For a moment let's ignore the non-existent topic, will this code work to validate the successful delivery to the topic which exists.

Comment: Yes; it will do that; but you need to figure out what's going on with the exception.

Comment: @GaryRussell I have a same issue. topic gives an error message (LEADER_NOT_AVAILABLE) . How can I fix it ? Here is my project link : github.com/Rapter1990/springbootkafka